# Can't install on Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 13.04, windows

I have downloaded several versions of Ubuntu and none are installing on my Windows 8 PC. I have tried with flash drives, CDs and several applications. Can anyone please help? I need these installed ASAP for school purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ and run it;
2. Use linuxliveusb to extract and modify the contents of your Ubuntu ISO to your USB drive (make sure to select 'format to FAT32');
3. When linuxliveusb is finished, close out of the window and continue reading >>>

Because you haven't given me specifics on your machine, I have no idea weather your PC uses UEFI or regular BIOS and what key it uses to access those menus, so I'll try to help you with as many key combinations I know. Here are the instructions to UEFI:

1. Reboot your PC. When the screen goes blank, press and hold 'F9'. If a menu pops up, go to step (). If not then try rebooting with this list of key combinations (one per boot, though):

"F1", "F2", "F6", "F8", "F10", "F11", "F12", "DELETE", "BACKSPACE", "ESC".

- If this works, use your up and down arrow keys to select different devices. You will want to look for the USB drive you named or linuxlive named (linuxlive will most likely name it 'MYLINUXLIVE'). When you find it, select it using the 'ENTER' key and look for a folder named 'boot'. Enter that that folder then look for a folder named 'grub'. If there is another folder, enter it and select the top most file. If that doesn't work, try the next file. If that doesn't work then navigate back up to the 'MYLINUXLIVE' folder and enter the folders 'EFI' then 'BOOT'. Select the top most file again, and if that doesn't work try the next.
- If none of these options worked for you, consider finding details about your PC (like manufacture and model), and post your specs back to askubuntu. Sorry if I could be no help. :C